# Script compilation failed at line 19 in procedure 'BusComp_PreWriteRecord':

Tags: siebel

I am getting the following error, when tries to save the following script.

"Script compilation failed at line 19 in procedure 'BusComp_PreWriteRecord':
Syntax error at Line 31 position 59:Expected ')'
(SBL-SCR-00128)"

```
function BusComp_PreWriteRecord ()
{

    var obj = TheApplication().GetBusObject("Service Request"); 
    var optybc = obj.GetBusComp("Service Request"); 
    optybc.ActivateField("SR Type"); 
    //optybc.ActivateField(â€œTypeâ€); 
    optybc.SetViewMode(3); 
    optybc.ClearToQuery(); 
    optybc.SetSearchSpec("SR Type",this.GetFieldV alue("SR Type")); 
    //optybc.SetSearchSpec(â€œTypeâ€,this.GetFieldV alue(â€œTypeâ€)); 
    optybc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardOnly); 
    if(optybc.FirstRecord()) 
    { 
        TheApplication().RaiseErrorText("Duplicate Records"); 
    } 
}
```

Does anyone knows the reason for the above error?

Comment: I hope its not the part where you have misspelled this.GetFieldV alue("SR Type")

Comment: I have corrected that. But still I am getting the same error for the below line:
var obj = TheApplication().GetBusObject("Service Request");

Comment: Sorry I'm so late. It really would help if you could tell us which line is the 31st (or the 19th in that function). Anyway, I'd try removing the 2 lines that you have commented out. Perhaps Siebel is having trouble analyzing the script once it finds those "weird unicode characters".

Comment: Actually there's no line as 31 :( I removed the commented lines, but still I am getting the same error. But as it seems, all okay.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are missing brackets in code that is "above" `PreWriteRecord()` 
for example these methods

[image]

Siebel compiles all event code as one large code, so missing parentheses in other places will create issue in subsequent events.